# Do I have a problem with variables not resetting in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, numpy, variables, jupyter-notebook, namespaces

I am running an algorithm in a Python notebook in Jupyter Notebook. It transforms data in numpy arrays and stores everything in a csv file.

The algorithm is transforming the data nicely, however, there are still unexpected points. I can't find any bugs in the algorithm but it is not working as expected:

- I have been running the algorithm several times with different data that are stored to variables with unchanging names. I always use "Restart and Clear Output" to clear the namespace before running the algorithm on different data. For example, I will store a numpy array to variable A on the first run of the algorithm and then click "Restart and Clear Output". Then I will store another numpy array of different values to variable A again on the second run and click "Run All". Yet, it seems some of the transformed data only makes sense if the old data was not fully cleared.
- Normally when I run the algorithm, the output csv file will be overwritten because I save it to the name "data.csv" everytime. However, today after I ran the algorithm, there were two data.csv files. This has never happened before but the problem with unexpected transformed data has always happened.

Whenever I use "Restart and Clear Output", the notebook otherwise works as expected. Running `%whos` afterwards outputs "Interactive namespace is empty" and the prompt numbers go back to `ln[1]`. I was still wondering if the problem was the variables, so I renamed them all. The unexpected data is still there. I am at a dead end now, do I have a problem with resetting variables? How could I test for that otherwise?

As an update: my code includes broadcasting two dimensional arrays to the third dimension and summing across axis 2. I read that this might create errors that could add up and the data I use contain tens of thousands of points. So I specified dtype=”float64” to increase precision, yet that increased the errors for some reason. Does that mean my algorithm is unstable?

Comment: Are your results perfectly reproducible by re-running all cells without restarting the kernel?

Comment: @MatthiasHuschle Yes. As an update: my code includes broadcasting two dimensional arrays to the third dimension and summing across axis 2. I read that this might create errors that could add up and the data I use contain tens of thousands of points. So I specified dtype=”float64” to increase precision, yet that increased the errors for some reason? However, that is the only thing that changed the output.